# T-SQL script to calculate elapsed time between multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

good afternoon I'm trying to generate a query in sql to know the time span used by each service order.
any help is appreciated.

example:

```
CITA    FECHACITA   MANODEOBRA  UNIDTIEMPO  MECANICO
261354  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO  09:30   10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA 
MARTINEZ 
261354  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO  09:35   10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA 
MARTINEZ 
261354  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO  09:40   10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA 
MARTINEZ 
261354  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO  09:45   10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA 
MARTINEZ 
261354  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO  09:50   10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA 
MARTINEZ 
261354  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO  09:55   10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA 
MARTINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    08:30   02 ERIK BENJAMIN 
GONZALEZ GODINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    08:35   02 ERIK BENJAMIN 
GONZALEZ GODINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    08:40   02 ERIK BENJAMIN 
GONZALEZ GODINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    08:45   02 ERIK BENJAMIN 
GONZALEZ GODINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    08:50   02 ERIK BENJAMIN 
GONZALEZ GODINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    08:55   02 ERIK BENJAMIN 
GONZALEZ 
GODINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    09:00   04 JUAN CARLOS MONTAÑEZ
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    09:05   04 JUAN CARLOS MONTAÑEZ
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    09:10   04 JUAN CARLOS MONTAÑEZ
```

so should be seen

```
CITA    FECHACITA   MANODEOBRA  UNIDTIEMPO  MECANICO
261354  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO  00:25   10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA 
MARTINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    00:25   02 ERIK BENJAMIN 
GONZALEZ GODINEZ 
261858  06/10/2017  M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO    00:10   04 JUAN CARLOS MONTAÑEZ
```

Comment: Hint: You want to use `GROUP BY` and you want to find the `DATEDIFF` between the `MIN` and `MAX` of UNIDTIEMPO.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us that that you have attempted to solve the problem, see [mcve].   Post some SQL you have tried, and this will help us better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG` to get the next time for each row (if such exists). Note, that we are grouping here using the `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [CITA] INT
    ,[FECHACITA] DATE
    ,[MANODEOBRA] VARCHAR(32)
    ,[UNIDTIEMPO] TIME
    ,[MECANICO] VARCHAR(64)

);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [UNIDTIEMPO], [MECANICO])
VALUES   ('261354', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO', '09:30', '10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA MARTINEZ')
        ,('261354', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO', '09:35', '10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA MARTINEZ')
        ,('261354', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO', '09:40', '10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA MARTINEZ')
        ,('261354', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO', '09:45', '10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA MARTINEZ')
        ,('261354', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO', '09:50', '10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA MARTINEZ')
        ,('261354', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 0 MANTENIMIENTO', '09:55', '10 LUIS ENRIQUE HERRERA MARTINEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '08:30', '02 ERIK BENJAMIN GONZALEZ GODINEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '08:35', '02 ERIK BENJAMIN GONZALEZ GODINEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '08:40', '02 ERIK BENJAMIN GONZALEZ GODINEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '08:45', '02 ERIK BENJAMIN GONZALEZ GODINEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '08:50', '02 ERIK BENJAMIN GONZALEZ GODINEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '08:55', '02 ERIK BENJAMIN GONZALEZ GODINEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '09:00', '04 JUAN CARLOS MONTAÑEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '09:05', '04 JUAN CARLOS MONTAÑEZ')
        ,('261858', '06/10/2017', 'M-M.O. 2 DIAGNOSTICO', '09:10', '04 JUAN CARLOS MONTAÑEZ');


SELECT [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO]
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [UNIDTIEMPO], LEAD([UNIDTIEMPO], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO] ORDER BY [UNIDTIEMPO])) AS [TimeInMinutes]
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY [FECHACITA]
        ,[UNIDTIEMPO];
```

[image]

We are using the `DATEDIFF` function to get our time difference in minutes. Having this result, what is left is to simply summarize the times for each group:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO]
          ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [UNIDTIEMPO], LEAD([UNIDTIEMPO], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO] ORDER BY [UNIDTIEMPO])) AS [TimeInMinutes]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO]
      ,CAST(CONCAT(SUM([TimeInMinutes]) / 60 , ':', SUM([TimeInMinutes]) % 60) AS TIME) AS UNIDTIEMPO  
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO];
```

[image]

Note, that you do not specify the SQL Data Type of the `UNIDTIEMPO` column, so  I am using time. If you are storing it as string, you need to cast it as `time`.

---

For `SQL Server 2008 R2` you can use the query below:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [UNIDTIEMPO], [MECANICO]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO] ORDER BY [UNIDTIEMPO]) AS [RowID]
    FROM @DataSource 
),
FinalDataSource AS
(
    SELECT DS1.[CITA], DS1.[FECHACITA], DS1.[MANODEOBRA], DS1.[MECANICO]
          ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DS1.[UNIDTIEMPO], DS2.[UNIDTIEMPO]) AS [TimeInMinutes]
    FROM DataSource DS1
    INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
        ON DS1.[CITA] = DS2.[CITA]
        AND DS1.[FECHACITA] = DS2.[FECHACITA]
        AND DS1.[MANODEOBRA] = DS2.[MANODEOBRA]
        AND DS1.[MECANICO] = DS2.[MECANICO]
        AND DS1.[RowID] = DS2.[RowID] - 1
)
SELECT [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO]
      ,CAST(CAST(SUM([TimeInMinutes]) / 60 AS VARCHAR(8)) +  ':' + CAST(SUM([TimeInMinutes]) % 60 AS VARCHAR(8)) AS TIME) AS UNIDTIEMPO  
FROM FinalDataSource
GROUP BY [CITA], [FECHACITA], [MANODEOBRA], [MECANICO];
```